# Division of two complex numbers in C

Tags: c, function, numbers, divide

i want to divide two complex numbers but I don't know why my result is always 0+0i.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
    
     typedef struct complex {
        int real;
        int imag;
    }complex;
    
    complex divide(complex n1, complex n2);
    
    int main() {
    
        complex n1, n2, rez;
    
        printf("real part n1: ");
        scanf("%d", &n1.real);
        printf("imag part n1: ");
        scanf("%d", &n1.imag);
    
        printf("real part n2: ");
        scanf("%d", &n2.real);
        printf("imag part n2: ");
        scanf("%d", &n2.imag);
    
        rez = divide(n1, n2);
        printf("Result= %d+%di", rez.real, rez.imag);
    }
    
    complex divide(complex n1, complex n2)
    {
        complex rez;
        rez.real = (n1.real * n2.real + n1.imag * n2.imag) / (n2.real * n2.real + n2.imag * n2.imag);
        rez.imag = (n1.imag * n2.real - n1.real * n2.imag) / (n2.real * n2.real + n2.imag * n2.imag);
        return rez;
    
    }
```

I think that the problem is in main but i'm not sure.

Comment: Use `double` as the internal type instead of `int`.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't know why my result is always 0+0i.

It's because you're using integer arithmetic. Switch to a floating point type, like `double`, instead:

```
typedef struct complex {
    int real;
    int imag;
}complex;
```

With integer arithmetic, you only get the integer part of the result, so e.g. `1 / 2` gives you `0`.

Comment: Did you mean to update the types to ```double``` in the code block?

Comment: @sj95126 Yes, but other changes (e.g. in the scanf() calls)will also be needed to make it work. I pasted the struct there because it makes the cause of the problem pretty obvious.